# How to get aggregation of child collection in mongodb and apply $count is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I want to sum counts values for each beacon. I'm using aggregate query but it returns with counts 0. Please let me know if there is mistake in query.

> **Sample Data**

```js
[                    {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5a8166392aa41ec66efc66bf"),
                        "userID" : "5a7c3410bdff0f0014181874",
                        "date" : ISODate("2018-02-08T11:04:54.000Z"),
                        "beacons" : [ 
                            {
                                "counts" : "2",
                                "UUID" : "red"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "counts" : "1",
                                "UUID" : "blue"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5a8166392aa41ec66efc66c0"),
                        "userID" : "5a7c3410bdff0f0014181874",
                        "date" : ISODate("2018-02-08T11:04:54.000Z"),
                        "beacons" : [ 
                            {
                                "counts" : "2",
                                "UUID" : "red"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "counts" : "1",
                                "UUID" : "blue"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
            
]
```

> **Query**

```js
                /* Query */

                    db.getCollection('CountsDetail')
                    .aggregate([
                    {
                      "$unwind":"$beacons"
                    },
                    {
                        "$group": {
                        "_id":"$beacons.UUID", "counts":{ "$sum":"$counts"}
                    }
                    }]);
```

> **Response**

```js
            /* Response */
              
                   {
                      "_id" : "red",
                      "counts" : 0
                   }
          
                   {
                     "_id" : "blue",
                     "counts" : 0
                   }
```

Response is returning 0 in sum, which is weird. Please correct what I am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Fix counts to have numeric values. $sum contain sum string values & Try `db.getCollection('CountsDetail')
                    .aggregate([
                    {
                      "$unwind":"$beacons"
                    },
                    {
                        "$group": {
                        "_id":"$beacons.UUID", "counts":{ "$sum":"$beacons.counts"}
                    }
                    }])`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry miss read your OP. Your `counts` field is nested so use a dot notation:

```
  "counts":{ "$sum":"$beacons.counts"}
```